# business catalyst & jquery cloud zoom

Tags: jquery, business-catalyst

I'm ok using cloud zoom on static sites but with adobe BC I'm lost. I need zoom on hover for the large product images but I'm not sure what code needs adding for it to work in BC or where to put it so the large image tag links to the zoom size image.

Answer (score 0):

Will you be uploading a big image specifically for zooming, besides the expected 'large' image? If so:

- Add the path to the zoom image in one of the 'Custom' product fields (I will use 'Custom 1' in this example).
- In your large product layout (`/Layouts/OnlineShop/large_product.html`), replace the {tag_largeimage} tag with something like this:

  ```html
  <!-- Create a Cloud Zoom in the usual way. -->
  <img src="{tag_largeimage_path}" id = "zoom1" class = "cloudzoom"
       data-cloudzoom = "zoomImage: '{tag_custom1}'" />
  ```

The other approach is to upload just the 'zoom' image, and have BC's image resizing ability downscale it for you, reducing your workload.

Assuming your large product layout expects a 'large' image at 300x400px, and the image you've uploaded is much bigger:

```html
<img src="{tag_largeimage_path}?Action=thumbnail&Width=300&Height=400&algorithm=proportional"
     id = "zoom1" class = "cloudzoom"
     data-cloudzoom = "zoomImage: '{tag_largeimage_path}'" />
```

Otherwise you may be able to use BC's built in zoom function, documented here: 
http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/134/bc_1342.html#main_Individual_Product__Large_

N.B.: The `_path` suffix in the image tag is not available for all image tags; some, such as webapp images, only accept `_value`.